# How do I create a jetty 6 and jetty 7 compatible jetty-web.xml file in the same war file?

Tags: jetty, jboss-weld, appserver

In Jetty 6 I need to create a `WEB-INF/jetty-web.xml` file which contains this:

```
<Configure id="webAppCtx" class="org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
```

But in Jetty 7 I need the same exact file `WEB-INF/jetty-web.xml` to contain this:

```
<Configure id="webAppCtx" class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
```

Both files differ (`org.mortbay` vs `org.eclipse`). How do I create 1 war file which is compatible with both jetty 6 and jetty 7?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Poor man's solution: **build 2 wars for Jetty**.

I am thinking about [using maven assembly scripts to build multiple wars](https://github.com/droolsjbpm/guvnor/tree/master/guvnor-distribution-wars/src/main/assembly), However, I need to completely duplicate the `jetty-web.xml` file for both versions in my sources.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this can be done in one file, but you could use an ANT build script to create two version-specific WARs (my bad if you're already doing this)

Before calling the war build, have ANT copy your Jetty 6 or 7 WEB-INF/jetty-web.xml file in your war basedir and then call something like:

```
<target name="buildwar">
        <buildnumber />
    <war basedir="dist/web" destfile="${warName}-jetty${jettyVersion}.war"
     webxml="dist/WEB-INF/web.xml">         
        <webinf dir="dist/WEB-INF/">
            <include name="**/*.jar" />
        </webinf>
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="displayName" value="${warDisplayName} for Jetty ${jettyVersion}" />
            <attribute name="Implementation-Version" value="${build.number}" />            
        </manifest>         
    </war>
</target>
```

Comment: That would give me 2 wars for Jetty, I need 1. But I am afraid you're right that that's the only way. I 've added my maven way too.